# Populating posting.php message field from form submission on phpBB3 forum

Tags: php, forum, phpbb

I'm trying to add a form button that will take a variable string and insert it into `$_POST['message']`, such that when someone presses my 'post this on forum' button it takes them to the new topic page with my variable string already in the message `textarea`.

I've been messing with `submit_post` and have a form that submits a new post correctly when it's completed, however I don't want it to submit straight away; all I want is for it to load `posting.php` with my string already in the message field. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alteration you can make to posting.php to let it accept get parameters
http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2119831

Here it is for the sake of completion:

Find the following in posting.php:

```
    if ($submit || $preview || $refresh)
```

Add the following on a line before it:

```
if( !$submit&& !$preview&& !$refresh&& !$save&& !$load&& !$delete&& !$cancel&& ( $mode== 'post'|| $mode== 'reply'|| $mode== 'quote' ) ) {
$post_data['post_subject']= utf8_normalize_nfc( request_var( 'subject', '', TRUE ) );
$message_parser->message= utf8_normalize_nfc( request_var( 'message', '', TRUE ) );
```

Voila! Test it with http://yourdomain/forum/posting.php?mode=post&f=2&**subject=hello**&**message=world**

Answer (score 1):

You might have to modify the source of phpBB3 in order to do this. Unless `posting.php` is programmed to accept data from `$_POST` and insert it into the message `textarea`, you'll have to program it to do so.

As an alternative, you could try doing this with JavaScript: You could pass the text to `posting.php` in a cookie or a session variable which then displays in a hidden `div` or `textarea` or some other means (I'd need more specific information about your environment to provide specifics) and then insert that text into the `textarea` using JavaScript after the page loads. This should be more upgrade safe, but obviously requires users to have JavaScript enabled.